# Hardness of Approximation of MAX-3SAT

Tags: satisfiability

This is probably a duplicate of [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12908/how-hard-is-finding-restricted-assignment-of-3-sat-satisfying-7-8-of-the-claus), but I need a somewhat blunter answer.  Let's say I have a polynomial time algorithm that finds an assignment that satisfies more than $\frac{7}{8}$ of the clauses of a satisfiable 3SAT instance.  Do I collect my million dollars from the Clay Institute for proving $P=NP$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that Håstad gave such an algorithm in 2000, see [On bounded occurrence constraint satisfaction](https://www.nada.kth.se/~johanh/boundedocc.pdf). His algorithm is stated for instances where each variable occurs at most $B$ times, and the advantage over 7/8 depends on $B$. The running time, however, seems not to depend on $B$.

In order to prove that P=NP, you need to find an algorithm which, given a satisfiable instance, satisfies at least $7/8+\epsilon$ clauses, for some *constant* $\epsilon>0$. This will enable you to distinguish between satisfiable instances and instances which are at most $7/8+\epsilon/2$ satisfiable, which is NP-hard as [my answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/12911/683) to the question you mention shows.

Comment: I _think_ I understand the difference, but now I'm further mystified.  Let's say my hypothetical algorithm finds an assignment that satisfies 90% of the clauses for a satisfiable instance.  Now it is presented with a problem where the maximum proportion of satisfiable clauses is, like, 95%.  How would my 90% algorithm distinguish between the two?

Comment: Your algorithm doesn't distinguish between these two cases. It distinguishes (for example) between satisfiable instances and those that are at most 89% satisfiable.

Comment: Aha, I think I get it.  To keep it concrete, distinguishing between 7/8th satisfiable and 100% satisfiable is in P, distinguishing between 89% satisfiable and 100% satisfiable is NP-hard (where that 89% is constant and independent of the problem).  You could use my hypothetical 90% solver to solve the real satisfiability problem by reducing an input formula $\phi$ in polynomial time to another formula $\phi'$ such that  $\phi'$ is 90% satisfied iff $\phi$ is SAT.  But if you can only achieve 7/8th, then you have gained nothing.

Comment: Right, you got it. It is actually conceivable that 89% or 90% could be improved to $7/8+f(n)$ for some $f(n)=o(1)$, but I'm not aware of any such result in the literature, and I don't know whether current technology is good enough to prove such a bound.